# Compile OpenSSL with the 'shared' option?

Tags: apache, openssl

On CentOS 5.4, OpenSSL compiles fine without 'shared' option. But when I passed that option the compilation fails with:

> /usr/bin/ld: libcrypto.a(x86_64-gcc.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `a local symbol' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

When I try: `./config shared CFLAGS=-fPIC`  that doesn't work.

What can I do to get OpenSSL to compile with the 'shared' option?

Thanks

Comment: Did you "make clean" between running without shared and running it with shared? What OpenSSL version is this?

Answer (score 32):

Same problem here, BUT usually Makefiles will consider environment variables for compiler or linker options.

So, if you place the `-fPIC` option *before* calling the configure script, it should take care of it. You can do it with:

```
CFLAGS=-fPIC ./config shared --prefix=/your/path
```

or

```
export CFLAGS=-fPIC
./config shared --prefix=/your/path
```

It worked for me.

Comment: +1 - Encountered this today on a totally different project, and can confirm this works perfectly. Just remember to `make clean` if you've already tried building it without this correct command line!

Answer (score 21):

There is an option `-fXXX` that you can pass to config so you can do it with:

```
./config -fPIC shared
```

Comment: Be sure to "make clean" prior to adding -fPIC if you have tried building before.

Comment: they need a 2KLOC Perl script to put together a few command line options and they can't even get it right on presumably the most popular platform (Linux x64). I'm sure there's a lesson in here somewhere.

Comment: Yup, it's called use GNU autoconf like everyone else!

Comment: I had tunnel vision on just getting the -fPIC flag to take that I wasn't adding the shared part. On it's own -fPIC doesn't seem to do anything so make sure you also add shared.

Answer (score 4):

## Compiling openssl

> Download your openssl tarball, unzip, and then ensure that the install directory is named `openssl`.
>
> I placed mine in /usr/local/openssl, so I'll use that in my example.

1. `sudo mv openssl-1.0.2u /usr/local/openssl && cd /usr/local/openssl`
2. `sudo make distclean`
3. `sudo ./config -fPIC -shared`
4. `sudo make && sudo install`

   > Now, add the openssl shared library to your PATH.
5. `vim ~/.profile
     Go
     export PATH="/usr/local/openssl/lib:$PATH"
     :wq`

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I built OpenSSL with shared libraries. Note that I'm using a cross compiler so I specify things most wouldn't.

```
# hop into the downloads folder
cd ~/Downloads
# get the branch of openssl you want
git clone -b OpenSSL_1_0_2-stable --single-branch https://github.com/openssl/openssl.git
# make an installation directory
mkdir openssl-install
# go into the cloned openssl directory
cd openssl
# absolute paths needed for the configure
# the "-fPIC -mhard-float" are CFLAGS specific to my project
# the "-shared" is what creates the .so files
# find your desired configuration with `./Configure LIST`
./Configure linux-mips32 --prefix=/home/myusername/Downloads/openssl-install --openssldir=/system/ssl -fPIC -mhard-float -shared
# run the make file (with my specific compiler)
make CC=mips-linux-gnu-gcc RANLIB=mips-linux-gnu-ranlib LD=mips-linux-gnu-ld MAKEDEPPROG=mips-linux-gnu-gcc PROCESSOR=MIPS
```

Comment: what ndk version did you use

Answer (score 1):

The OpenSSL version 1.0 (published today) works fine with the shared option

Comment: Well i have still the same problem with 1.0.0j

Comment: @arved Confirmed on Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS x64 with CMake v2.8: using `-fPIC shared` complains about `libcrypto.a` not being built with `-fPIC`.