# How to build Paho MQTT C static libraries on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: cmake, openssl, static-libraries, paho, ninja

I'm trying to build the static libraries of Eclipse Paho MQTT C on a Raspberry Pi 3 B+. As a prerequisite it is necessary to have the static version of the OpenSSL library on the system.

First, I attempted to get it using the following commands:

```
git clone git://git.openssl.org/openssl.git
cd openssl
git checkout OpenSSL_1_1_1a
./config -static
sudo make install
```

This does produce a `libssl.a` File in `/usr/local/lib`. However, when I then try to build the static libraries of Paho using the following commands, it fails with the error below:

```
git clone https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.c.git
mkdir /tmp/build.paho
cd /tmp/build.paho
cmake -GNinja -DPAHO_WITH_SSL=TRUE -DPAHO_BUILD_STATIC=TRUE ~/paho.mqtt.c
ninja
```

[image]

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libssl.a(methods.o): relocation R_ARM_MOVW_ABS_NC against ‘a local symbol’ can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/libssl.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
```

The suggested solution to this problem in several Stackoverflow questions seems to be to build the static OpenSSL library with the `shared` flag: `./config shared -static`
But even then, building of the static Paho libraries fails with the exact same error.

I should add that I did not have any troubles with this procedure on other hardware architectures. Could this problem be related to the Raspberry Pi in any way? How do I solve it?

Comment: Please, do not post and image with error message. Instead, post the error message as **text**. Among the other reasons, it is a rule of Stack Overflow. See [ask].

Comment: Sorry, error added as text.

Comment: "Standard" problem about `recompile with -fPIC`. You need OpenSSL to be compiled with that option. See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19022607/3440745) about the possible way for doing this.

Comment: Did you try adding another defintion `-DCMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE=ON` to your `cmake` command to enable PIC for all targets? (Suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38297422/3987854))

Answer (score 0):

`CFLAGS=-fPIC ./config shared -static` seems to have worked for OpenSSL. However, after building the static Paho MQTT C libraries, which finishes without any errors, there are no static libraries to be found anywhere.

If I then look in `/usr/local/lib`, I only find the dynamic .o libraries there, no static .a ones. Why is this not working on the Pi but worked perfectly fine on a different system?